# print 2 pages per sheet with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, printing

i am trying definitely to print 2 pages per sheet (the sheets are pre-selected and are active) with VBA but this option seems not be possible

I've tried the following:

```
With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
.FitToPagesWide = 1
.FitToPagesTall = 2
.PrintOut copies:=1
end with
```

however my printer does not print correctly. Any suggestion?

Comment: `.PrintOut` is a method of the worksheet, not the worksheet's `PageSetup`.

Comment: I see, but how can we tell the printer to print 2 sheets per page. PageSetup does not seem to be an option?

Comment: How would you do that manually?

Comment: file, print, layout, pages per sheet 2, print button

Comment: Have you tried recording a macro when you do it, and then look at the code it gives you?

Comment: Printing 2 pages per sheet, or 2 sheets per page?

Comment: yes it was one of my idea but did not work, I dont know if the file, print is something different (or maybe different on a Mac). if you have any good idea let me know

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub PrintAll()

Dim sh As Worksheet

Dim wb As Workbook

Set wb = ThisWorkbook

For Each sh In wb.Worksheetssh.PrintOut
```

sh.FitToPagesWide = 1

sh.FitToPagesTall = 2

sh.PrintOut copies:=1

Next sh

End Sub